# Python - resume web session from urllib2 after manual browser login

Tags: python, browser, authentication, web-scraping

Say, I browse to a website (on intranet too) that require a login to access the contents. I will fill in the required fields... e.g. username, password and any captcha, etc. that is required for logging in from the browser itself.

Once I have logged in into the site, there are lots of goodies that can be scraped from several links and tabs on the first page after logged in.

Now, from this point forward (that is after logged in from the browser).. I want to control the page and downloads from urllib2... like going through page by page, download pdf and images on each page, etc.

I understand that we can use everything from urllib2 (or mechanize) directly (that is login to the page and do the whole thing).

But, for some sites.. it is really a pain to go through and find out the login mechanism, required hidden parameters, referrers, **captcha**, cookies and pop ups.

Please advise. Hope my question makes sense.

**In summary, i want the initial login part done using the web browser manually... and then take over the automation for scraping through urllib2.**

Comment: what you ask is complex and vague... try to be more specific

Comment: Sorry.. I will edit now to see if I can be more specific.

Comment: I don't think it's all that complex or vague... I'm actually surprised it hasn't been asked before. I did a lot of digging and couldn't find any duplicates.

Comment: Although the editing was necessary, I don't think the down-voting was really needed. It's an interesting question and it was possible to understand the meaning from the first iteration.

Comment: @ihightower Perhaps you can mark the answer that comes closest to solving your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you consider [Selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/)? It's about browser automation instead of http requests (urllib2), and you can manipulate the browser in between steps.

Comment: That doesn't help in getting past a captcha.

Comment: No but you can build a pause in the Selenium script to interact with the Selenium-controlled browser yourself.

Comment: Ah of course. For some reason I was thinking Selenium was like mechanize, but I remember now it's much more. This is probably neater than my solution.

Comment: i knew about selenium and have reconsidered it after your comment. It somehow works.. like running the default python script after my recording session... I can now take control of the browser from python idle and test it, and it somehow works.... 1) However, can i use urllib2 now to do my work to open subsequent pages in the same script.. sending POST parameters, etc. after getting in to the site through selenium instead of using driver.get()... 2) Can I just not see the browser window?. pls advise.

Comment: No, that would be very difficult. The selenium browser has the session.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the `cookielib` module.

http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html

You can log on using your browser, then export the cookies into a Netscape-style `cookie.txt` file. Then from python you'll be able to load this and fetch the resource you require. The cookie will be good until the website expires your session (often around 30 days).

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
cj.load('cookie.txt')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://example.com/resource")
```

There are add-ons for Chrome and Firefox that will export the cookies in this format. For example:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lopabhfecdfhgogdbojmaicoicjekelh

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i want initial part manual and later part auto.. due to captcha for example. using mechanize, i still cannot send the required captcha field in post. However, if I used the browser.. I can login and enter captcha normally and only do the automation part through mechanize or urllib2.

Comment: In the case where there's a captcha you definitely will need the manual browser part. So logon with the real browser, then export the cookie.txt file, then load it into MozillaCookieJar and use either urllib2 or mechanize. Urllib2 will almost certainly suffice.

Comment: @ jleahy. i tried to use your method using firefox cookies. And, after browsing to the page.. and export cookie. I used your above code with my url. But, the page goes to login start page only.  I can't get into the site even with using cookies and session id. any ideas.. how i can improve and audit?